# IBM Worklight 7.0 'WL.Device.getID' is giving error in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

`WL.Device.getID` is giving error in Windows 8 and windows phone 8 application.
I am previweing application in IE and it shows error.

> Unable to get property 'getID' of undefined or null reference

Comment: WL.Device.getID is not supported in the Windows 8 environment, but it should work in the Windows Phone 8 environment - this is currently being tested. We'll get back to you...

Answer (score 2):

I tested it and it works for me.
This is the code (main.js) I ran:

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    var options = {
            onSuccess: succ,
            onFailure: fail
    };
    WL.Device.getID(options);
}

function succ(data) {
    alert('succ ' + JSON.stringify(data));
}

function fail() {
    alert('fail');
}
```